# There has to be a better way to do this

Tags: python

The following was approved in my class, but it looks so bulky. Would there be a better way to write this?

```
def tel_kleine_letters(string):
    aantal_kleine_letters = 0
    for karakter in string:
        if 'a' <= karakter <= 'z': # letter is kleine letter
            aantal_kleine_letters += 1
    return aantal_kleine_letters
    lijst = ["Een", "Twee", "Drie"]

    for woord in lijst:
        aantal = tel_kleine_letters(woord)
        print("er zitten", aantal, "klene letters in", word)

    totaal_kleine_letters = 0
    for woord in lijst:
        for letter in woord:
            if 'a' <= letter <= 'z': # letter is kleine letter
                totaal_kleine_letters += 1

    print("er zitten totaal", totaal_kleine_letters, "kleine letters in", lijst)
```

Comment: For code that works, I suggest posting on our sister site [codereview.se]. Be sure to read their guidelines before posting.

Comment: also, I tried to fix the indentation, but it still looks wrong. Please take a look and edit your code as appropriate to reflect what you actually have.

Comment: Pleas edit the title to be descriptive of your issue!

Comment: One thing I see: you could use `aantal` to calculate `totaal_kleine_letters` instead of looping again.

Comment: @ddejohn While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus* (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ will do.

Answer (score 2):

`tel_kleine_letters` could be written more simply by taking advantage of `str.islower()` and `sum`:

```
def tel_kleine_letters(string):
    return sum(c.islower() for c in string)
```

Also, you're re-implementing your entire `tel_kleine_letters` function to recalculate the number that you've already gotten in the earlier loop.  You could just keep track of the total in the loop where you print all the individual words:

```
woords = ["Een", "Twee", "Drie"]
totaal = 0

for w in woords:
    k = tel_kleine_letters(w)
    print(f"er zitten {k} kleine letters in {w}")
    totaal += k

print(f"er zitten totaal {totaal} kleine letters in {woords}")
```

If you needed to compute the total independently of that loop, you could use the `sum` of `tel_kleine_letters` for each string in the list, similar to how we used it earlier to sum all the lowercase letters in a single string:

```
totaal = sum(tel_kleine_letters(w) for w in woords)
print(f"er zitten totaal {totaal} kleine letters in {woords}")
```

Another option would be to `join` all the strings together and then use your function to count the lowercase letters in the joined string:

```
totaal = tel_kleine_letters(''.join(woords))
print(f"er zitten totaal {totaal} kleine letters in {woords}")
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Code-Apprentice also pointed out, you can add `aantal` to `totaal_kleine_letters` instead of doing all of the work again. It would then look something like this:

```py
def tel_kleine_letters(string):
    aantal_kleine_letters = 0
    for karakter in string:
        if 'a' <= karakter <= 'z': # letter is kleine letter
            aantal_kleine_letters += 1
    return aantal_kleine_letters

lijst = ["Een", "Twee", "Drie"]

totaal_kleine_letters = 0
for woord in lijst:
    aantal = tel_kleine_letters(woord)
    print("er zitten", aantal, "klene letters in", word)
    totaal_kleine_letters += aantal

print("er zitten totaal", totaal_kleine_letters, "kleine letters in", lijst)
```

You can also try using the python builtin function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and a [`lambda expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda). It will probably be less performant but for a small amount of characters it will be fine.

```py
def tel_kleine_letters(string):
    return sum(
        map(
            lambda word: len(list(filter(lambda c: "a" <= c <= "z", word))),
            ["Een", "Twee", "Drie"],
        )
    )
```